# SOAP request uneffective on smartserver2.2

Tags: soap

I am new here. I work as a developper on a very small company. I am in charge of developping a software (asp.net/c#) in order to monitor street lightings via smartservers (old version : 2.2).
I use SOAP messages to change the configuration and the values of each individual lamp (via datapoint).

I mostly succeeded to create schedulers and also to add datapoints.
But I am facing an issue when I want to add presets to a datapoint.

For example, these are 3 presets that could be used by the scheduler to control the lamp power (nviLampValue):

- ON with a power lamp value of 100% represented by the formatted value '100.0 1'
- OFF with a power lamp value of 0% represented by the formatted value '0.0 0'
- PRESET1 at 80% with the formatted value '80.0 1'

I created a SOAP request (SET) to configure the presets for a datapoint (i.e. Net/LON/P68/OLC[0]/nviLampValue_1) but after a lot of trials and despite having no errors, the smartserver still ignore my request.

If someone have an idea about what is wrong with the request, it would help me a lot.

Thanks by advance

Regards,

Here is the SOAP request I made :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mes="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <mes:messageProperties>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:UCPTuniqueId>cid:38089712644</mes:UCPTuniqueId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:UCPTipAddress>192.168.1.222</mes:UCPTipAddress>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:UCPTport>8080</mes:UCPTport>
      </mes:messageProperties>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:Set xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
        <mes:iLonItem xsi:type="Item_Coll" xmlns:xsi="xsi">
          <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
          <mes:Item xsi:type="Dp_Cfg" xmlns:xsi="xsi">
             <mes:UCPTname>Net/LON/P68/OLC[0]/nviLampValue_1</mes:UCPTname>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <mes:UCPTannotation>Dp_In;xsi:type=\"LON_Dp_Cfg\"</mes:UCPTannotation>
             <mes:UCPTbaseType LonFormat="#8000010128000000[4].UCPTbaseType">BT_STRUCT</mes:UCPTbaseType>
            <UCPTformatDescription>#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_switch</UCPTformatDescription>
            <mes:ValueDef>
                <mes:UCPTindex>0</mes:UCPTindex>
                <mes:UCPTname>OFF</mes:UCPTname>
                <mes:UCPTvalue LonFormat='#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_switch'>0.0 0</mes:UCPTvalue>
            </mes:ValueDef>
            <mes:ValueDef>
                <mes:UCPTindex>1</mes:UCPTindex>
                <mes:UCPTname>ON</mes:UCPTname>
                <mes:UCPTvalue LonFormat='#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_switch'>100.0 1</mes:UCPTvalue>
            </mes:ValueDef>
            <mes:ValueDef>
                <mes:UCPTindex>2</mes:UCPTindex>
                <mes:UCPTname>PRESET1</mes:UCPTname>
                <mes:UCPTvalue LonFormat='#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_switch'>80.0 1</mes:UCPTvalue>
            </mes:ValueDef>
          </mes:Item>
        </mes:iLonItem>
      </mes:Set>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And here is the response of the smartserver (seems to indicate no error, but no processing too)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <p:messageProperties xmlns:p="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
         <p:UCPTtimeStamp>2022-01-10T17:33:18.040+01:00</p:UCPTtimeStamp>
         <p:UCPTuniqueId>0300003B44F2</p:UCPTuniqueId>
         <p:UCPTipAddress>192.168.1.222</p:UCPTipAddress>
         <p:UCPTport>8080</p:UCPTport>
         <p:UCPTlastUpdate>2022-01-10T16:23:36Z</p:UCPTlastUpdate>
         <p:UCPTprocessingTime>21</p:UCPTprocessingTime>
      </p:messageProperties>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SetResponse xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
         <iLonItem xsi:type="Item_Coll">
            <UCPTfaultCount>0</UCPTfaultCount>
            <UCPTcurrentConfig>4.0</UCPTcurrentConfig>
         </iLonItem>
      </SetResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution that seems to work. I share in case someone could face the same (or a similar) problem.

This is what I found that worked after sending the request using SOAPUI:

- I had to edit the < Enveloppe >, < MessageProperties > and < Set > tags with the correct namespaces.
- I also added more parameters in the  tag but I didn't check if they are all necessary, except UCPTname, UCPTannotation, UCPTFormatDescription, UCPTDirection and UCPTbaseType and  that are important to define the presets.

Regards,

Here is the request that worked for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <Header>
        <messageProperties xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/"/>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Set xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
            <iLonItem>
                <Item xsi:type="Dp_Cfg">
                    <UCPTname>Net/LON/P68/OLC[0]/nviLampValue_1</UCPTname>
                    <UCPTannotation>Dp_In;xsi:type=\"LON_Dp_Cfg\"</UCPTannotation>
                    <UCPThidden>0</UCPThidden>
                    <UCPTformatDescription>#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_switch</UCPTformatDescription>
                    <UCPTlength>2</UCPTlength>
                    <UCPTdirection LonFormat="#8000010128000000[4].UCPTdirection">DIR_IN</UCPTdirection>
                    <UCPTbaseType LonFormat="#8000010128000000[4].UCPTbaseType">BT_STRUCT</UCPTbaseType>
                    <UCPTmaxFields>2</UCPTmaxFields>
                    <SCPTmaxSendTime>0</SCPTmaxSendTime>
                    <SCPTminSendTime>0</SCPTminSendTime>
                    <SCPTmaxRcvTime>0</SCPTmaxRcvTime>
                    <ValueDef>
                        <UCPTindex>0</UCPTindex>
                        <UCPTname>OFF</UCPTname>
                        <UCPTvalue LonFormat="#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_switch">0.0 0</UCPTvalue>
                    </ValueDef>
                    <ValueDef>
                        <UCPTindex>1</UCPTindex>
                        <UCPTname>ON</UCPTname>
                        <UCPTvalue LonFormat="#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_switch">100.0 1</UCPTvalue>
                    </ValueDef>
                    <ValueDef>
                        <UCPTindex>2</UCPTindex>
                        <UCPTname>PRESET1</UCPTname>
                        <UCPTvalue LonFormat="#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_switch">80.0 1</UCPTvalue>
                    </ValueDef>
                </Item>
            </iLonItem>
        </Set>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).